# HTML element added to the DOM as a string

Tags: html, jquery

I've got a jsFiddle here to demonstrate the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/mbwu3ap7/2/

Outcome, I want to add a button to the input when the mouse enters the input.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control guidInput"/>
```

here is my jQuery:

```
 $(document).on("mouseenter",
    ".guidInput",
    function(e) {
        this.after('<button id="fooBar">add user</button>');
    });
```

What I want is a button adding to the DOM, instead I get a double quoted string added:

[image]

Notes: I'm using 'on' as the input will be dynamically added to the DOM after the page has rendered.

Comment: Is this what you look for? https://jsfiddle.net/x6k0fyjb/

Comment: Try wrapping it in a jQuery object: `this.after($('<button id="fooBar">add user</button>'));` I'm not 100% sure, has been a long time since I worked with jQuery.

Comment: `this` is a DOM node and not a jQuery object, hence you're using [`Element.after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) and not [`$.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after)

Comment: ... so you want `$(this).after()` instead though are you sure you want to add a new `<button>` element **every time** you move your mouse over the input?

Comment: @Phil your CSS only solution is nice.  Just needs a wrapper so the button doesn't disappear - I took the liberty of tweaking it:  https://jsfiddle.net/umfhvwcp/

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks but OP seems to want the button to stick around after which the CSS doesn't do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Thanks for the comments and the hints.

Just wrap "this" into a jquery selector and it will work as expected:

https://jsfiddle.net/q85pfmex/

```
     function(e) {
        $(this).after('<button id="fooBar">add user</button>');
    });
```